# django modelform inheritance

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-forms, super

I've run into a django error that's got tearing out my hair. Background: I have a set of models inheriting from each other, and I'm trying to build a set of forms with a parallel structure.

Here's the base type for an object creation form:

```
class CreateSharedObjectForm(ModelForm): 
  def save(self, status, object_type, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
    print "*********Got here!!!**************"
    shared_object = super(ModelForm,self).save( commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
    shared_object.status = status
    shared_object.object_type = object_type

    if commit:
      shared_object.save()
    return shared_object
```

Here's an inherited form type:

```
class NewBatchForm(CreateSharedObjectForm):
  def save(self, status, object_type, batch_options, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
    print "Checkpoint A"
    batch = super(CreateSharedObjectForm,self).save( status, object_type, commit=False, *args, **kwargs )
    print "Checkpoint B"

    if commit:
      batch.save(*args, **kwargs)
    return analysis

  class Meta:
    model = batch
```

I call the inherited type from a view script:

```
 form = NewAnalysisForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
  new_analysis = form.save(
    status = 'X',
    object_type  = 'Batch',
    batch_type = 'temp',
  )
```

And it throws this error:

```
save() takes at most 2 non-keyword arguments (4 given)
```

If I change the "super" line to this:

```
batch = super(CreateSharedObjectForm,self).save( status, object_type, commit=False, *args, **kwargs )
```

I get this error:

```
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    null value in column "parent_project_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Even wierder, django's trace output gives me this:

```
Checkpoint A
Checkpoint B
```

Before returning a HTTP 500 error.

As far as I can tell, the super line in the save method in NewBatchForm is never calling CreateSharedObjectForm. I'm aware that the [super method can be tricky](http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/), but this is just single inheritance, and I can't figure out why the method for the superclass *never* gets called.

What's going on here?  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you don't want `super(NewBatchForm, self).save` inside `NewBatchForm`?

(you have `super(CreateSharedObjectForm, self)`

Comment: I tried it and it throws: save() got multiple values for keyword argument 'commit'

Comment: Thanks for a good, quick answer.  I can't believe I missed that myself.